# What is wrong with this program? Can't debug

Tags: python, debugging, typeerror

I have been spending a few hours trying to debug this program but I have not figured out why it is not working properly. This program is supposed to read test results, get result file from user at console, write summary line to output file, and print flag to console if any results are outside the normal range.

```
# str file_name, test_name, output_line, result_str, min_res_str, max_res_str
# file results_file, output_file
# int result, min_res, max_res
# bool done


done = False
flag = True

file_name = input("Please enter the name of the file, without the .txt   extension: ")
results_file = open(file_name+".txt")
output_file = open(file_name+"_output.txt", "w")

while not done:
# read a test result
test_name = results_file.readline()
test_name == test_name.rstrip("\n")
if test_name != "":
    result_str = results_file.readline()
    if result_str != "":
        result = str(result_str)
        min_res_str = results_file.readline()
        if min_res_str != "":
            min_res = int(min_res_str)
            max_res_str = results_file.readline()
            max_res = int(max_res_str)
        else:
            done = True
    else:
        done = True
else:
    done = True
# process
if not done:
    output_line = output_file.write(test_name+"\t" + str(result)+"\t")
    if min_res > result:
        output_line = "low\n"
    elif max_res < result:
        output_line = "high\n"
    else:
        output_line = "within normal limits\n"
        flag = False
    output_file.write(output_line)

results_file.close()
output_file.close()

if flag:
     print("Test result out of range: check results.")
```

the error i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/saves/midtermprep.py", line 42, in <module>
if min_res > result:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

I have an input txt document for this program

```
NA
141
136
145
K
4.8
3.5
5.3
CL
100
98
107
CO2
20
22
32
CALCIUM
9.6
8.4
```

Comment: Result is a string, min_res is int. Fail to compare

Comment: `result = str(result_str)` your casting `result` to a `string`. try changing `if min_res > result:` to `if min_res > int(result)`:

Comment: After a bit more research, would it make more sense to change `if min_res > result:` to `if min_res > float(result):`  since the numbers are not just integers but floats as well? I've tested it out but however, received another error..     `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/saves/midtermprep.py", line 32, in <module>
    max_res = float(max_res_str)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Answer (score 3):

You compare an int (min_res or max_res) to a string (result), which does not work.  Convert result to an int before comparing

```
if min_res > int(result):
    output_line = "low\n"
elif max_res < int(result):
    output_line = "high\n"
```

Comment: @ptierno I've changed these and as a result the error changes     'Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python34/saves/midtermprep.py", line 30, in <module>
        min_res = int(min_res_str)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.5\n''

Comment: Looking at your sample file, the values for K and CALCIUM are actually floats and not ints.  For each time you convert a string to an int in your program now (aka `int(...)`), you should instead convert it to a float (aka `float(...)`)